# WaveForm on IOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, avfoundation

I'm looking for how to draw the sound amplitude.

I found http://supermegaultragroovy.com/2009/10/06/drawing-waveforms/ but i have some problems. How get a list of floating-point values representing the audio?

Comment: So... what have you found so far ?

Comment: Which sound do you mean?  Are you trying to use the microphone, or a sound file stored on the device?

Comment: This answer here is pure gold: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5032775/drawing-waveform-with-avassetreader/7388332#7388332

Comment: Simon, I meand sound already recorded from microphone.

Comment: Generally the individual samples are integers -- eg, 16-bit numbers.  You'd need to convert them to float yourself, if you want a float representation.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Thank all.

I found this example here: [Drawing waveform with AVAssetReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5032775/drawing-waveform-with-avassetreader) , changed it and developed a new class based on.

This class returns UIImageView.

```
//.h file
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface WaveformImageVew : UIImageView{

}
-(id)initWithUrl:(NSURL*)url;
- (NSData *) renderPNGAudioPictogramLogForAssett:(AVURLAsset *)songAsset;
@end


//.m file
#import "WaveformImageVew.h"

#define absX(x) (x<0?0-x:x)
#define minMaxX(x,mn,mx) (x<=mn?mn:(x>=mx?mx:x))
#define noiseFloor (-50.0)
#define decibel(amplitude) (20.0 * log10(absX(amplitude)/32767.0))
#define imgExt @"png"
#define imageToData(x) UIImagePNGRepresentation(x)

@implementation WaveformImageVew

-(id)initWithUrl:(NSURL*)url{
    if(self = [super init]){
        AVURLAsset * urlA = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:url options:nil];
        [self setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:[self renderPNGAudioPictogramLogForAssett:urlA]]];
    }
    return self;
}

-(UIImage *) audioImageLogGraph:(Float32 *) samples
                   normalizeMax:(Float32) normalizeMax
                    sampleCount:(NSInteger) sampleCount 
                   channelCount:(NSInteger) channelCount
                    imageHeight:(float) imageHeight {

    CGSize imageSize = CGSizeMake(sampleCount, imageHeight);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageSize);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor);
    CGContextSetAlpha(context,1.0);
    CGRect rect;
    rect.size = imageSize;
    rect.origin.x = 0;
    rect.origin.y = 0;

    CGColorRef leftcolor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
    CGColorRef rightcolor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];

    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);

    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1.0);

    float halfGraphHeight = (imageHeight / 2) / (float) channelCount ;
    float centerLeft = halfGraphHeight;
    float centerRight = (halfGraphHeight*3) ; 
    float sampleAdjustmentFactor = (imageHeight/ (float) channelCount) / (normalizeMax - noiseFloor) / 2;

    for (NSInteger intSample = 0 ; intSample < sampleCount ; intSample ++ ) {
        Float32 left = *samples++;
        float pixels = (left - noiseFloor) * sampleAdjustmentFactor;
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, intSample, centerLeft-pixels);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, intSample, centerLeft+pixels);
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, leftcolor);
        CGContextStrokePath(context);

        if (channelCount==2) {
            Float32 right = *samples++;
            float pixels = (right - noiseFloor) * sampleAdjustmentFactor;
            CGContextMoveToPoint(context, intSample, centerRight - pixels);
            CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, intSample, centerRight + pixels);
            CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, rightcolor);
            CGContextStrokePath(context); 
        }
    }

    // Create new image
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    // Tidy up
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();   

    return newImage;
}



- (NSData *) renderPNGAudioPictogramLogForAssett:(AVURLAsset *)songAsset {

    NSError * error = nil;    

    AVAssetReader * reader = [[AVAssetReader alloc] initWithAsset:songAsset error:&error];

    AVAssetTrack * songTrack = [songAsset.tracks objectAtIndex:0];

    NSDictionary* outputSettingsDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:

                                        [NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatLinearPCM],AVFormatIDKey,
                                        //     [NSNumber numberWithInt:44100.0],AVSampleRateKey, /*Not Supported*/
                                        //     [NSNumber numberWithInt: 2],AVNumberOfChannelsKey,    /*Not Supported*/

                                        [NSNumber numberWithInt:16],AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey,
                                        [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO],AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey,
                                        [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO],AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey,
                                        [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO],AVLinearPCMIsNonInterleaved,

                                        nil];


    AVAssetReaderTrackOutput* output = [[AVAssetReaderTrackOutput alloc] initWithTrack:songTrack outputSettings:outputSettingsDict];

    [reader addOutput:output];
    [output release];

    UInt32 sampleRate,channelCount;

    NSArray* formatDesc = songTrack.formatDescriptions;
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < [formatDesc count]; ++i) {
        CMAudioFormatDescriptionRef item = (CMAudioFormatDescriptionRef)[formatDesc objectAtIndex:i];
        const AudioStreamBasicDescription* fmtDesc = CMAudioFormatDescriptionGetStreamBasicDescription (item);
        if(fmtDesc ) {

            sampleRate = fmtDesc->mSampleRate;
            channelCount = fmtDesc->mChannelsPerFrame;

            //    NSLog(@"channels:%u, bytes/packet: %u, sampleRate %f",fmtDesc->mChannelsPerFrame, fmtDesc->mBytesPerPacket,fmtDesc->mSampleRate);
        }
    }

    UInt32 bytesPerSample = 2 * channelCount;
    Float32 normalizeMax = noiseFloor;
    NSLog(@"normalizeMax = %f",normalizeMax);
    NSMutableData * fullSongData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    [reader startReading];    

    UInt64 totalBytes = 0; 

    Float64 totalLeft = 0;
    Float64 totalRight = 0;
    Float32 sampleTally = 0;

    NSInteger samplesPerPixel = sampleRate / 50;    

    while (reader.status == AVAssetReaderStatusReading){

        AVAssetReaderTrackOutput * trackOutput = (AVAssetReaderTrackOutput *)[reader.outputs objectAtIndex:0];
        CMSampleBufferRef sampleBufferRef = [trackOutput copyNextSampleBuffer];

        if (sampleBufferRef){
            CMBlockBufferRef blockBufferRef = CMSampleBufferGetDataBuffer(sampleBufferRef);

            size_t length = CMBlockBufferGetDataLength(blockBufferRef);
            totalBytes += length;


            NSAutoreleasePool *wader = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

            NSMutableData * data = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:length];
            CMBlockBufferCopyDataBytes(blockBufferRef, 0, length, data.mutableBytes);


            SInt16 * samples = (SInt16 *) data.mutableBytes;
            int sampleCount = length / bytesPerSample;
            for (int i = 0; i < sampleCount ; i ++) {

                Float32 left = (Float32) *samples++;
                left = decibel(left);
                left = minMaxX(left,noiseFloor,0);

                totalLeft  += left;



                Float32 right;
                if (channelCount==2) {
                    right = (Float32) *samples++;
                    right = decibel(right);
                    right = minMaxX(right,noiseFloor,0);

                    totalRight += right;
                }

                sampleTally++;

                if (sampleTally > samplesPerPixel) {

                    left  = totalLeft / sampleTally; 
                    if (left > normalizeMax) {
                        normalizeMax = left;
                    }                    
                    // NSLog(@"left average = %f, normalizeMax = %f",left,normalizeMax);                    

                    [fullSongData appendBytes:&left length:sizeof(left)];

                    if (channelCount==2) {
                        right = totalRight / sampleTally; 


                        if (right > normalizeMax) {
                            normalizeMax = right;
                        }                        

                        [fullSongData appendBytes:&right length:sizeof(right)];
                    }

                    totalLeft   = 0;
                    totalRight  = 0;
                    sampleTally = 0;

                }
            }                        

            [wader drain];            

            CMSampleBufferInvalidate(sampleBufferRef);

            CFRelease(sampleBufferRef);
        }
    }    

    NSData * finalData = nil;

    if (reader.status == AVAssetReaderStatusFailed || reader.status == AVAssetReaderStatusUnknown){
        // Something went wrong. Handle it.
    }

    if (reader.status == AVAssetReaderStatusCompleted){
        // You're done. It worked.

        NSLog(@"rendering output graphics using normalizeMax %f",normalizeMax);

        UIImage *test = [self audioImageLogGraph:(Float32 *) fullSongData.bytes 
                                    normalizeMax:normalizeMax 
                                     sampleCount:fullSongData.length / (sizeof(Float32) * 2) 
                                    channelCount:2
                                     imageHeight:100];

        finalData = imageToData(test);
    }        

    [fullSongData release];
    [reader release];

    return finalData;
}

@end
```

Comment: Excellent code here.  Had to import <CoreMedia/CoreMedia.h> and <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h> into the .h file to get this up and running

Comment: it will generate two graphs in one image can i have single plz?

Comment: @jignesh-b maybe you used stereo multimedia?

Comment: pls comment this part of code (channelCount==2) { ... }

Comment: can we create waveform like this app https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/mp3-chopper/id576330551?mt=8 using above code? i.e like view in scrollview

Comment: @IgorShubin hmmm suggest me. how to go forward?

Comment: FYI, this is incorporated into a library at https://github.com/fulldecent/FDWaveformView

Answer (score 14):

Been reading your question and created a control for this. Looks like this:

[image]

Code here:

https://github.com/fulldecent/FDWaveformView

Discussion here:

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/fdwaveformview

**UPDATE 2015-01-29**: This project is going strong and making consistent releases. Thanks for SO for all the exposure!

Answer (score 2):

I can give you reference of the one that I have implemented in my application. It was apple's example. Here is the example of [`AurioTouch`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/aurioTouch/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007770) which analyzes 3 types of sound audio. Apple has still not provided to analyse directly the audio waves... so this example also uses the Mic to analyse the sound...

Amongst 3 I have used only Oscilloscope for analysing the amplitude effect. I have to change that code drastically to match my requirement, so best of luck if you are going to use...

You can also see one more example using such amplitude : [SpeakHere](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SpeakHere/Introduction/Intro.html) of Apple

Answer (score 1):

This is the code I have used to convert my audio data (audio file ) into floating point representation and saved into an array.

```
-(void) PrintFloatDataFromAudioFile {

NSString *  name = @"Filename";  //YOUR FILE NAME
NSString * source = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:name ofType:@"m4a"]; // SPECIFY YOUR FILE FORMAT

const char *cString = [source cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

CFStringRef str = CFStringCreateWithCString(
                                            NULL,
                                            cString,
                                            kCFStringEncodingMacRoman
                                            );
CFURLRef inputFileURL = CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath(
                                                      kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                      str,
                                                      kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle,
                                                      false
                                                      );

ExtAudioFileRef fileRef;
ExtAudioFileOpenURL(inputFileURL, &fileRef);


  AudioStreamBasicDescription audioFormat;
audioFormat.mSampleRate = 44100;   // GIVE YOUR SAMPLING RATE 
audioFormat.mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
audioFormat.mFormatFlags = kLinearPCMFormatFlagIsFloat;
audioFormat.mBitsPerChannel = sizeof(Float32) * 8;
audioFormat.mChannelsPerFrame = 1; // Mono
audioFormat.mBytesPerFrame = audioFormat.mChannelsPerFrame * sizeof(Float32);  // == sizeof(Float32)
audioFormat.mFramesPerPacket = 1;
audioFormat.mBytesPerPacket = audioFormat.mFramesPerPacket * audioFormat.mBytesPerFrame; // = sizeof(Float32)

// 3) Apply audio format to the Extended Audio File
ExtAudioFileSetProperty(
                        fileRef,
                        kExtAudioFileProperty_ClientDataFormat,
                        sizeof (AudioStreamBasicDescription), //= audioFormat
                        &audioFormat);

int numSamples = 1024; //How many samples to read in at a time
UInt32 sizePerPacket = audioFormat.mBytesPerPacket; // = sizeof(Float32) = 32bytes
UInt32 packetsPerBuffer = numSamples;
UInt32 outputBufferSize = packetsPerBuffer * sizePerPacket;

// So the lvalue of outputBuffer is the memory location where we have reserved space
UInt8 *outputBuffer = (UInt8 *)malloc(sizeof(UInt8 *) * outputBufferSize);



AudioBufferList convertedData ;//= malloc(sizeof(convertedData));

convertedData.mNumberBuffers = 1;    // Set this to 1 for mono
convertedData.mBuffers[0].mNumberChannels = audioFormat.mChannelsPerFrame;  //also = 1
convertedData.mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize = outputBufferSize;
convertedData.mBuffers[0].mData = outputBuffer; //

UInt32 frameCount = numSamples;
float *samplesAsCArray;
int j =0;
    double floatDataArray[882000]   ; // SPECIFY YOUR DATA LIMIT MINE WAS 882000 , SHOULD BE EQUAL TO OR MORE THAN DATA LIMIT

while (frameCount > 0) {
    ExtAudioFileRead(
                     fileRef,
                     &frameCount,
                     &convertedData
                     );
    if (frameCount > 0)  {
        AudioBuffer audioBuffer = convertedData.mBuffers[0];
        samplesAsCArray = (float *)audioBuffer.mData; // CAST YOUR mData INTO FLOAT

       for (int i =0; i<1024 /*numSamples */; i++) { //YOU CAN PUT numSamples INTEAD OF 1024

            floatDataArray[j] = (double)samplesAsCArray[i] ; //PUT YOUR DATA INTO FLOAT ARRAY
              printf("\n%f",floatDataArray[j]);  //PRINT YOUR ARRAY'S DATA IN FLOAT FORM RANGING -1 TO +1
            j++;


        }
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is my answer, thx all geek

```
obj-c
```

here is code:

```
-(void) listenerData:(NSNotification *) notify
{
int resnum=112222;
unsigned int bitsum=0;
for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
{
    bitsum+=(resnum>>(i*8))&0xff;
}
bitsum=bitsum&0xff;
NSString * check=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%x %x",resnum,bitsum];
check=nil; 
self.drawData=notify.object;``
[self setNeedsDisplay];
}

-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
NSArray *data=self.drawData;
NSData *tdata=[data objectAtIndex:0];
double *srcdata=(double*)tdata.bytes;
int datacount=tdata.length/sizeof(double);
tdata=[data objectAtIndex:1];
double *coveddata=(double*)tdata.bytes;

CGContextRef context=UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGRect bounds=self.bounds;
CGContextClearRect(context, bounds);
CGFloat midpos=bounds.size.height/2;
CGContextBeginPath(context);

const double scale=1.0/100;
CGFloat step=bounds.size.width/(datacount-1);
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0, midpos);
CGFloat xpos=0;
for(int i=0;i<datacount;i++)
{
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, xpos, midpos-srcdata[i]*scale);
    xpos+=step;
}
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, bounds.size.width, midpos);

CGContextClosePath(context);
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
CGContextFillPath(context);

CGContextBeginPath(context);

const double scale2=1.0/100;
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0, midpos);
xpos=0;
for(int i=0;i<datacount;i++)
{
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, xpos, midpos+coveddata[i]*scale2);
    xpos+=step;
}
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, bounds.size.width, midpos);

CGContextClosePath(context);
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
CGContextFillPath(context);
}
```