# Waveform generation from an audio file or live audio recording in iOS

Tags: iphone, xcode4.5, core-audio, audio-recording, waveform

I want to generate the waveform from an audio file or from live audio recording in my app, i have seen [this](https://github.com/uliwitness/UKSoundWaveformView) tutorial but its built for cocoa platform not for cocoa touch and i have also google many tutorial but i am still unable to find out the tutorial which could help me to generate audio waveform signals like SoundCloud app.
I have also tried apples aurioTouch but its too complex to understand.

Please help me and suggest a good example of waveform generation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8298610/waveform-on-ios