# Equalizer from audio data

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, core-audio, audio-streaming

I have a mp3 file, so I need to play it, and display an equalizer (like in attached image).
So playing is not problem, but I have no idea how to measure power of current playing sample's dBs based on frequency.

By which steps I can get data for displaying dBs of current sample?
*As I guess, I need to get some array of powers in different frequencies, am I right?*

Here is examples of what I want to achieve:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7oeb-OIOe-0
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PwmUhTDr0Y0

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [WaveForm on IOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8298610/waveform-on-ios)

Comment: No, I need equalizer and not wafeform

Comment: Use core audio, http://www.deluge.co/?q=content/coreaudio-iphone-creating-graphic-equalizer

Answer (score 2):

The standard way to transform from time domain to frequency domain is a [Fourier Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform).

Apple [provide one in vDSP](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/vDSP_Programming_Guide/UsingFourierTransforms/UsingFourierTransforms.html) (vector Digital Signal Processing).

Walkthrough using this library [here](https://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2012-10-26-fourier-transforms-and-ffts.html).  Another example (for bats!) [here](http://batmobile.blogs.ilrt.org/fourier-transforms-on-an-iphone/).

By the way, I wouldn't call this an equalizer - to me that would be something that alters the relative components of a waveform in different frequency bands.