# Is it possible to fetch live audio amplitude with react-native 'expo'?

Tags: javascript, react-native, audio, expo

I am trying to build a react-native audio visualisation animation. For this i need some kind of audio amplitude data of the current playing track.

The Javascript Audio API provide a "decodeAudioData" method which seems to do just that : Providing a data stream of the current playing audio amplitudes.

JS audio API seems to be browser only so i can't use it.

Is there something similar using expo-av or react-native ?

Comment: Related: [React Native Audio Visualization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33194943/react-native-audio-visualization).

Comment: i am not sure it’s related because i am looking for live audio amplitudes and not a pre-calculated waveform of the whole audio file

Answer (score 1):

I just implement it in https://github.com/flyskywhy/react-native-live-audio-fft , you can just use PowerLevel(), or more complex FrequencyHistogramView() and WaveSurferView()