# Drawing Waveform with AVAssetReader and with ARC

Tags: iphone, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, core-audio, waveform

I'm trying to apply Unsynchronized's answer ([Drawing waveform with AVAssetReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5032775/drawing-waveform-with-avassetreader/9507813#9507813)) while using ARC. There were only a few modifications required, mostly release statements.  Many thanks for a great answer!  I'm using Xcode 4.2 targeting iOS5 device.

But I'm getting stuck on one statement at the end while trying to invoke the whole thing.

Method shown here:

```
-(void) importMediaItem {

    MPMediaItem* item = [self mediaItem];

    waveFormImage = [[UIImage alloc ] initWithMPMediaItem:item completionBlock:^(UIImage* delayedImagePreparation){

        [self displayWaveFormImage];
    }];

    if (waveFormImage) {
       [self displayWaveFormImage];
    }
}
```

On the call to initWithMPMediaItem I get the following error:

```
Automatic Reference Counting Issue.  Receiver type 'UIImage' for instance message 
does not declare a method with selector 'initWithMPMediaItem:completionBlock:'
```

Since I do have the method initWithMPMediaItem declared in the class header, I really don't understand why I'm getting this error.

```
- (id) initWithMPMediaItem:(MPMediaItem*)item
       completionBlock:(void (^)(UIImage* delayedImagePreparation))completionBlock;
```

Been trying to wrap my head around this for several hours now but to no avail. Is my method declaration wrong for this type of method? Thanks!

Comment: The main issue is that you are calling initWithMPMediaItem on a UIImage. It is declared as a method in your class (I think, can't really know until you show us the header it is declared in) so it is expecting to be called on self (which I assume is not a UIImage). You need to decide how you want this this method to act - should it be in a UIImage category?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `initWithMPMediaItem` should be declared as an initializer for `UIImage`. So you should declare it inside a `UIImage` category in your header file:

```
@interface UIImage (MPMedia)

- (id) initWithMPMediaItem:(MPMediaItem*)item
   completionBlock:(void (^)(UIImage* delayedImagePreparation))completionBlock;

@end
```

Comment: I entered your answer and it worked!  I had the method lumped in with all my other methods in the header.  Something else new to learn. Thank you sch and sosborn!