# Draw a waveform while playing audio iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, avaudioplayer, waveform

I want to **draw a waveform** while **Playing audio**??

I checked in the below link 
also checked with EZAudio and audiograph it doesn't help me

[Drawing waveform of audio on iOS without using AVAudioPlayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9809160/drawing-waveform-of-audio-on-ios-without-using-avaudioplayer)

Is there any tutorial or sample project in similar way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Drawing waveform with AVAssetReader](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5032775/drawing-waveform-with-avassetreader)

Comment: This is not a dupe of the question about using AVAssetReader. This question appears to be related to reading the waveform data in real time as an asset is playing, not in displaying the entire waveform without playing.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)startForFilePath:(NSString *)filePath
{
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
    _playTime = 0.0f;
    _audioFilePath = filePath;

    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:_audioFilePath];
    NSError *error = nil;
    _player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
    if (_player == nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"player: %@ %ld %@", [error domain], (long)[error code], [[error userInfo] description]);
        UIAlertView *alert =
        [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @""
                                   message: [error localizedDescription]
                                  delegate: nil
                         cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                         otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        return;
    }
    _player.numberOfLoops = 0;
    [_player prepareToPlay];
    _player.meteringEnabled = YES;

    NSTimeInterval duration = _player.duration;
    _waveUpdateFrequency = duration/(SOUND_METER_COUNT/2);
    [_player play];

    _timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:_waveUpdateFrequency target:self selector:@selector(updateMeters) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)updateMeters
{
    [_player updateMeters];
    if ((![_player isPlaying]) || (_playTime >= 60.0f)) { //60s
        [self stop];
        return;
    }
    _playTime = _player.currentTime;

    [self addSoundMeterItem:[_player averagePowerForChannel:0]];
}

#pragma mark - Sound meter operations
- (void)shiftSoundMeterLeft
{
    for(int i = 0; i < SOUND_METER_COUNT - 1; i++) {
        _soundMeters[i] = _soundMeters[i+1];
    }
}

- (void)shiftSoundMeterRight
{
    for(int i = SOUND_METER_COUNT - 1; i >= 0 ; i--) {
        _soundMeters[i] = _soundMeters[i-1];
    }
}

- (void)addSoundMeterItem:(int)lastValue
{
    if (_isMeterRight) {
        [self shiftSoundMeterRight];
        [self shiftSoundMeterRight];
        _soundMeters[0] = lastValue;
        _soundMeters[1] = lastValue;
    }
    else {
        [self shiftSoundMeterLeft];
        [self shiftSoundMeterLeft];
        _soundMeters[SOUND_METER_COUNT - 1] = lastValue;
        _soundMeters[SOUND_METER_COUNT - 2] = lastValue;
    }

    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

#pragma mark - Drawing operations
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    // Draw sound meter wave
    [_meterWaveColor set];

    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1.0);
    CGContextSetLineJoin(context, kCGLineJoinRound);

    int baseLine = _frameRect.size.height/2;
    int multiplier = 1;
    int maxValueOfMeter = _frameRect.size.height/2 - 5;
    for(CGFloat x = SOUND_METER_COUNT - 1; x >= 0; x--)
    {
        multiplier = ((int)x % 2) == 0 ? 1 : -1;

        CGFloat y = baseLine + ((maxValueOfMeter * (MAX_LENGTH_OF_WAVE - abs(_soundMeters[(int)x]))) / MAX_LENGTH_OF_WAVE) * multiplier;

        if(x == SOUND_METER_COUNT - 1) {
            CGContextMoveToPoint(context, x * (_frameRect.size.width / SOUND_METER_COUNT), y);
            //CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, x * (_frameRect.size.width / SOUND_METER_COUNT) + 1, y);
        }
        else {
            CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, x * (_frameRect.size.width / SOUND_METER_COUNT), y);
            //CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, x * (_frameRect.size.width / SOUND_METER_COUNT) + 1, y);
        }
    }

    CGContextStrokePath(context);
}
```

Comment: I think you missed header file.